# Cannot Find Edge AAD OIDC App Launcher Extension

Tags: openid-connect, microsoft-edge-extension

I used to have an Edge browser extension (Edge ONLY I think) that could be used to launch AAD OIDC Apps, stipulate whether to use id_token, token, access_token in the AAD auth request, etc.  Anyway, I somehow have lost this from my browser and trying to add it back but cannot seem to find it anywhere.  Wondering if anyone knows if the extension has been renamed or taken out of circulation?  This used to be very helpful to track all the default and optional claims configured for the AAD OIDC App without needing to have the App/Service up and running, so I could capture the info, fine tune settings, etc. before going live with turning App/Service servers on, registered in DNS for Internet Accessibility, etc.

Anyway, hoping someone might know where I can find this Edge Extension?

Research on the Internet for the past week or so, just not finding anything related to this Edge extension.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it may be difficult to find the specific extension you mentioned without more information(such as the name, extension ID). I searched the Edge extensions store and found [this one](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/saml-wsfederation-and-o/boffpaecgbbojpkboijhbmhecoefdehi?hl=en-US) using the `OIDC` keyword, not sure if it's what you're referring to.

As far as I know, Edge doesn't keep track of the extensions you install and uninstall. If you're lucky, if you sync the extension to another machine and turn off this setting, the extension will remain on that machine. You can try to check it.